# How to check that url is a valid image source using urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I want to check if an image exists on the given URL using python(urllib2). For example how do I check that an image exists on this url.

```
https://www.example.com/image.png
```

If not exist then now its retriving a html content, its not good, i want to check that url has an image then only execute the next code.
Sample Code,

> ```
>         try:
>             image = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
>             image_base64 = base64.encodestring(image)
>             Set image if exist
>         except:
>             default image set
> ```

Comment: What is wrong with your example code pseudo code? Do you not know how to make your example into real code?

Comment: @Mr.Python i just want to check that url have image source ? some time url redirect index.html so its always return me some values(html/image) but i want to check only images

Comment: @l'L'l thanks for detail information link! but its same like url redirect index.html page so response will always get but i want to check that have image source?